# How to convert a big number to normal in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, bignum

I receive my data in which there is:

```
deviceTimestamp:1531564520188828
```

I want to convert this timestamp in human date and use this code:

```
moment.unix(timestamp).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm:ss A');
```

But when I console.log(deviceTimestamp), it returns me this

```
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 15, c: [ 15, 31656237268093 ] },
```

And timestamp convert does not work.

Comment: That number doesn't look like a unix timestamp

Comment: Where does that deviceTimestamp come from? Looks to me like it has more than just milliseconds in it. If you cut the last 3 digits the given timestamp is  Sat Jul 14 2018.

Comment: Removing the last 6 digits gets to 2018-07-14T10:35:20.

Comment: OK but when I want to work with deviceTimestamp,it returns me BigNumber { s: 1, e: 15, c: [ 15, 31656237268093 ] }

Comment: @VahagnAleksanyan where are you getting the number from?

Comment: i would encourage you to have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat NPM module.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you are trying to do something like this:

```js
deviceTimestamp = 1531564520188828;

var d = new Date(deviceTimestamp);
console.log(d);
console.log(d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear());

var dateString = d.toGMTString();
console.log(dateString);
```

**NOTE**:

- It seems like an incorrect timestamp hence, the invalid year.
- This is an approach using Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

The number you have appears to be micro seconds since midnight 1st January 1970.

Forget the Unix timestamp and divide the number you have by 1,000 for the JavaScript timestamp.

```js
var deviceTimestamp = 1531564520188828;

var date = moment(deviceTimestamp/1000).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm:ss A');

console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js is very interesting to play .

```
let deviceTimestamp = 1531564520188828
var date = moment(deviceTimestamp/1000).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm:ss A');
```

If you are looking to learn in detail about Moment.js , open https://momentjs.com/ : right click then click on inspect and try all type of possibilities in console.

[image: Click here to see console result]

Answer (score -2):

```
function removeLast6(str) {
   str = str.toString();
   str = str.slice(0, -6);
   str = parseInt(str);
   return str;
}

function convertToHumanDate(timestamp) {
   return moment.unix(timestamp).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm:ss A');
}

const timestampNumber = await removeLast6(1531564520188828);

const date = await convertToHumanDate(timestampNumber);
```

Comment: Why on earth would you convert the number to a string to do integer division.

Comment: Why are you using await on functions that are not async?

Comment: Because area when I write this functions,all write asynch

Comment: To be honest, it wasn't mentioned in your original question and is not really relevant to the problem

Comment: I want to convert a big number to normal,after I want to convert timestamp to human date

Comment: Which big number library are you using?

Comment: Only I create last 6 elements,without any library

Comment: Where does `deviceTimestamp:1531564520188828` come from?